# How to send push notification to particular group members using parse?

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, push-notification

I am developing a social messaging app using parse as a backend. I need to send push notification to the group members when someone texted in the group.

My code is:

```
PFQuery* getMembers = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Group"];
[getMembers whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:groupId];
[getMembers includeKey:PF_RECENT_USER];
[getMembers findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSArray *ar = [[NSArray alloc]init];
        ar=[[objects objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"members"];
        NSLog(@"members %@",ar);
        PFQuery *queryInstallation = [PFInstallation query];
        [queryInstallation whereKey:PF_INSTALLATION_USER matchesKey:PF_RECENT_USER inQuery:getMembers];

        PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
        [push setQuery:queryInstallation];
        //[push setMessage:text];
        NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              text, @"alert",
                              @"ursound.caf", @"sound",
                              @"Increment", @"badge",
                              // @"Optionally a type was set", @"type",
                              nil];
        [push setData:data];
        [push sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
         {
             if (error != nil)
             {
                 NSLog(@"SendPushNotification send error.");
             }
         }];
       }
}];
```

Kindly guide me to correct my mistake.

Comment: What happens then -> no push is sent, or only to the wrong people? Did you check the parse console? What is the error returned?

Comment: yes i checked it shows push sent 0

Comment: and if you try to do the same query from the push console , what happens? The problem might be in the queryInstallation, no?

Comment: Yes it send pushes from push console

Comment: How are you sending a push from the console? i.e., whats your segment target

Answer (score 0):

You can send push notification to gruop members by creating channel and then subscribe the user to that channel .
Then you can send push notification to particular channel.

Visit https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications for more help for creating channel and send notification using channel.

Comment: Could you please guide me with some sample code related to my code?

Comment: @Ragul have you visit above link.  you can see there proper guidelines and code.